# Static HTML page in a Share AMP

Tags: alfresco

I have made an [AMP](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-modules-amp-intro.html) for Alfresco Share.

Now, I want that AMP to also serve a static HTML page when installed.

What is the best way to do that?

I could create an [Alfresco Share Web Script](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-surf-web-scripts.html), but that would be overkill, right?

Comment: Have you created that page in that amp??else refer this doc link http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-page.html

Comment: @vikash: The page must be provided by my AMP. I have tried that method, it works so feel free to post an answer based on it. It requires 3 files for a single file, so I hope something less verbose exists, but if not that will do. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source AMP package, create a folder `src/web-resources/`

In the `file-mapping.properties` have an entry for `/web-resources=/` eg

```
/config=/WEB-INF/classes
/web-resources=/
```

Your AMP's contents should then be something like:

```
Archive:  build/dist/Custom500.amp
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2017-04-28 15:28   lib/
      136  2013-07-23 08:50   module.properties
        0  2016-04-01 10:26   web-resources/
    14643  2016-04-01 10:26   web-resources/error500.jsp
     4286  2016-02-03 10:11   web-resources/favicon.ico
       41  2014-08-13 23:37   file-mapping.properties
---------                     -------
    19458                     6 files
```

When that AMP is installed, the files under the `web-resources` folder from the AMP (which were in `src/web-resources` before) will be dropped into the route of the Share webapp and can be served directly by Tomcat

(This example is to override the favicon and 500 error page for Share, but it's much the same for just adding custom web pages instead of overriding built-in web-served resources!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way suggested by @vikash, if you find something better please post a new answer, thanks!

In your Share AMP, add the following 3 files:

- File `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/templates/mypage.ftl` containing just the HTML of your static page.
- File `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/template-instances/mypage.xml` containing `<template-instance><template-type>mypage</template-type></template-instance>`.
- File `src/main/amp/config/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/pages/mypage.xml` containing this:

```
<page>
    <template-instance>mypage</template-instance>
    <authentication>none</authentication>
</page>
```

Then compile and redeploy your Share AMP.
The page should be visible at `http://localhost:8080/share/page/mypage`